# expressJS server returing Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'send' and how to serve html files

Tags: html, node.js, express, server

i have these html pages **signIn, SignUp, Index**.
i want to make express server 
code

```
var express= require("express");
var app= express();

app.get('/',function(request , response){
    request.send("demo page");

})

  var server =app.listen(3010, function(){
    console.log("server running on port "+ server.address().port);
})
```

when tying on browser

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'send'

why it is not working , i have changed port but invalid.
And also server my above html files using ExpressJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to replace

```
request.send("demo page");
```

with

```
response.send("demo page");
```

to make it work.

***Reference***: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

To make it serve `index.html` file on root use this code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

If you want to serve all static files use this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

But doing this you should be aware that everybody will have read access to all the files within your root directory. To fix this put all your html, js, css files to `/public` directory, and rewrite previous line like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Thus, when requesting `http://yoursite.com/test.html` you will get `public/test.html` file.

Comment: thank you very much, please also tell how to serve html files. i want to server index file on root

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I edited my question. Please see changes.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I edited my answer one more time. Good luck!